# How to replace text with a random number in SQL?

Tags: sql, heidisql

I have HeidiSQL and I have a 3MB query I need to run but I would like to replace certain text/values with a random number. How would I do that?

and I need to replace it, because there's a lot of rows.

```
INSERT INTO creature (`guid`, `id`, `map`, `zoneId`, `areaId`, `spawnMask`, `PhaseId`, `PhaseGroup`, `modelid`, `equipment_id`, `position_x`, `position_y`, `position_z`, `orientation`, `spawntimesecs`, `spawndist`, `currentwaypoint`, `curhealth`, `curmana`, `MovementType`, `npcflag`, `unit_flags`, `dynamicflags`, `VerifiedBuild`) VALUES
('@CGUID+0', 83855, 1116, 0, 0, 3, '0', 0, 0, 0, 1504.222, -2147.853, 90.73972, 0.6455684, 7200, 10, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 21463), -- 83855 (Area: 7120) (possible waypoints or random movement)
('@CGUID+1', 81244, 1116, 0, 0, 3, '0', 0, 0, 0, 1514.845, -2106.458, 92.60474, 2.908402, 7200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21463), -- 81244 (Area: 7120) (Auras: 163908 - 163908)
('@CGUID+2', 81244, 1116, 0, 0, 3, '0', 0, 0, 0, 1484.29, -2122.714, 92.58028, 1.293478, 7200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21463), -- 81244 (Area: 7120) (Auras: 163908 - 163908)
```

So basically I want to replace just where @CGUID+ is and just add a random number (preferabbly between 1-999999). Therefore it would add onto the current number to be like:

'4820940'
'2850331'
'2854962'

Note every last digit isn't changing, it's just the first text that's being replaced. But I need it to be random.

Comment: Just to confirm: you need to do that because you need to scramble data?

Comment: Also, since HeidiSQL is only a tool, may I know which database you are profiling/managing: MySQL, SQLServer or Postgres?

Comment: @Chris welcome to SO. you need to give us quite a bit more information when you post. what does your query look like? what DB are you trying to access? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL or SQLServer, a way to do that would be like this:

```
SELECT Replace(real_field1,'value to be replaced','new value') as scrambled_field1
FROM <any table>
WHERE <filter>
```

If you show your query, I could help you out.

Based on your SQL command, you could try something like this. I'm simplifying your query just to show syntax:

```
insert into table(column1) values (REPLACE('@CGUID+1','@CGUID',FLOOR(RAND()*(99999-1)+1))
```

Comment: Yes I'm using MySQL. But you'll have to forgive me of my lack of knowledge. I'm not sure what all to fill in there. I want to basically replace the text '@CGUID+' But there's like 5k rows and I want them all to have a random number.

Comment: Ok, please put your query on the question and show some examples of the replacements you want to make.

Comment: I can't. The query is 3MB and way too long. There's 5990 rows. Am I able to post it?

Comment: Paste the query command (SELECT ... FROM ...) and something like 3 rows and show how you want to replace the values on them.

Comment: The problem is that I need to do the same for all 5000+ rows. Any ideas?

Comment: How have you generated the SQL statement? This should be done during this time. Or you should create a script in some language of your preference, like java, c#, python, etc to do that for you.

Comment: Sorry, where exactly do I put it? On top of the query of this?:  INSERT INTO creature (`guid`, `id`, `map`, `zoneId`, `areaId`, `spawnMask`, `PhaseId`, `PhaseGroup`, `modelid`, `equipment_id`, `position_x`, `position_y`, `position_z`, `orientation`, `spawntimesecs`, `spawndist`, `currentwaypoint`, `curhealth`, `curmana`, `MovementType`, `npcflag`, `unit_flags`, `dynamicflags`, `VerifiedBuild`) I just put it on top of that?

Comment: On the values clause.

Answer (score 0):

Run the INSERT INTO statement as you have shown in your question.
Afterwards you run the following query:

```
UPDATE creature
    SET guid = REPLACE(guid, '@CGUID+', ROUND((RAND() * (999999-1))+1))
    WHERE guid LIKE '@CGUID+%'
```